# git reset hard, but no changes on graph when pushing

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a gitlab repo, made commit and merge.

[image: I want to roll back my history my commit and merge history.]

[image: My local repo log.]

I want to be on id: `9bc6dd4`.

Attempts I am making:

```
git log --oneline --graph -5
git reset --hard 9bc6dd4
git clean -f -d
git fetch --all
git push -u origin +master
```

When I push to remote repo no changes on remote repo .

Comment: Try to avoid using images-of-text in questions: see [ask].

Comment: Solved: I was in wrong branch and were rolling back and pushing it to wrong branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question text has:

> Attempts I am making:
>
> ```
> git log --oneline --graph -5
> git reset --hard 9bc6dd4
> git clean -f -d
> git fetch --all
> git push -u origin +master
> ```

while your image marked "my local repo log" begins with:

```
user@user-dekstop:~Desktop/work/front$ git log --oneline --graph -5
*   4efe036 (HEAD -> development, origin/mybranch, ...) ...
```

provided I have not made any typos during transcription.  That means your *current branch* is `development`, not `master`.  Note the `HEAD -> development` text.  Hence your `git reset` will adjust your branch name `development`.  Your `git push`, however, says to push `master` to `master` (with `--force` via `+`).  Since your own `master` did not move and still names the same commit as `origin/master`, this `git push` has no effect.

Comment: Hello dear Sir, so my current branch must be "development" and i must - "push --force origin +development"?

Comment: This depends on what you want the *other* Git to do. When you run `git push origin`, the next argument(s) after that tell your Git which commit(s) to send if any—your Git will send any that you have, that they don't, that they need—and then what to ask or command the other Git to set some name or names to. You choose both the commit hash ID(s) to make sure they have, and the name(s) to request updates to, with your *refspecs*.

Comment: A *refspec* is a multipart item: it has an optional leading `+` sign meaning `--force`, a *source* part which—for push at least—chooses a commit, and a *destination* part which determines the name you'll ask their Git to set. Running `git push origin master:master` means *turn my name `master` into a hash ID, then make sure they have that commit, then ask them to set their name `master` to that hash ID.*

Comment: If you want to ask their Git to update their branch named `development`, you could, e.g., run `git push origin 1234567:development`, assuming you have a commit whose hash ID is `1234567`. Here the source would be a raw hash ID and the destination would be their branch name `development`. That's probably not what you want to do, though. So the first step here is to determine what you really want to have happen.

Comment: Thank you for respond, i want to roll back to id: 9bc6dd4 and make the main red flow line to be "master" as it was before. Since i am the only who using this git, can you please help typing what i should type. Thank you

Comment: You want to roll *what* back to `9bc6dd4`, though? Remember that there are two repositories involved: yours, on your laptop, and some server Git somewhere (on GitLab). If you want to roll your own `master` back, you should `git checkout master` first, then run the `git reset --hard` you used before. You can then ask the GitLab Git repository to move *its* `master` as you have been trying to do so far.

Comment: Remember that *each Git repository* (each clone) has *its own branches*. Git in general likes to add commits to branches, so it's easy to "move forward" and harder to "move back". That's why this `git reset` sequence is complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it done, with your help. My attempts: git checkout master, git reset --hard 9bc6dd4, git clean -f -d, git fetch --all, git push origin --force master:master. Now i little bit understand in witch branch i am, and where to push.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to revert the remote `master` branch to commit `9bc6dd4`, there are several ways to do that :

a. just instruct `git` to force push `9bc6dd4` to `master` :

```sh
git push --force-with-lease origin 9bc6dd4:master

# anything that points to '9bc6dd4' can be used :
# after your 'git reset --hard' command : HEAD or development point to that commit
git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD:master
git push --force-with-lease origin development:master
```

b. switch to your local `master` branch first, reset your local branch, then force push :

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard 9bc6dd4
git push --force-with-lease
```

If your local `master` branch is set to track `origin/master`, then the last command will be equivalent to `git push --force-with-lease origin master:master`.